# Is it possible for python to accept an integer and a string in one statement?

Tags: python

What I mean is like if a user wanted to enter 100 cats and I wanted to store it in a variable, how would I do that. Eg.

```
print("how many cats are there")
amountofcats = input() #If it was just numbers then int input but I do not know if you     
want to add strings and integers
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> inp = input('How many cats are there?')
How many cats are there?100 cats
>>> a, b = inp.split(' ')
>>> a
'100'
>>> b
'cats'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to split it into 2 variables based off the entered space.

`amountofcats, animaltype = input().split(' ') print(amountofcats, animaltype)`

You could always leave it to be split later though.

`ans = input() amountofcats, animaltype = ans.split(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

just write this:

```
print("how many cats are there")
amountofcats = input()
import re
re.findall(r".\d",amountofcats)
```

this gives the output as a list so u can just print it like this:

```
print(re.findall(r".\d",amountofcats)[0])
```

this method works even without spaces